# Hiding files in iOS

Tags: ios, macos

I have some videos on my iPhone 5S and I don't know if there is a way of hiding them like in other OSs (e.g., Symbian) or not.

Does anyone know how to hide files (such as video or photo files) in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature by default on iOS.

if you want to hide directly videos or photos in the camera roll, that's not possible without a jailbreak.

After a fast search, i found some app that lock the access to their content like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-photo+video-safe-app/id447983569?mt=8). But you have to move the files to these apps.

With a jailbroken device, it's much simpler you can do it [from the built-in terminal](http://www.ehow.com/how_7692249_hide-files-iphone.html).

Comment: OK & thank you. My iOS version is 7.0.3, you think how much time I should wait for a good jailbreak for that?

Comment: You may ask this to the teams who works on this. I have no idea nor an influence on that.

Comment: I did that since you wanted me to do that!